# SOA BPEL Process is not loaded

Tags: oracle, wsdl, soa, bpel

I recently deployed a service to the server and then I began receiving the below error. I reverted the service back to the way it was before this error occurred and deployed to the server, however the error continues to occur. Does anybody know what could cause this error and how to fix it?

I am not very experienced with SOA so please let me know if more information is required here.

Thanks you in advance.

```
-<messages> 
-<input> 
-<Invoke_MapProdRuleexecute_InputVariable> 
-<part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="payload"> 


-<MapProductInputxmlns="http://www.pop.net/ws/Rules/MapProductRule/xsd/v1/MapProductRule"> 
<ProductType> 
 Paper Maps
</ProductType>
</MapProductInput>
</part>
</Invoke_MapProdRuleexecute_InputVariable>
</input>
-<fault> 
-<bpelFault> 
<faultType> 
0
</faultType>
-<remoteFault xmlns="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"> 
-<part name="summary"> 
<summary> 
Process not found.
the BPEL process "MapProductRuleProcess" with revision "1.0" is not loaded.
The process was not initialized properly, or the process was disabled.
Set the logging level to debug mode, check the log for the underlying 
exception trace related to this process loading problem.
</summary>
</part>
-<part name="code"> 
<code> 
2178
</code>
</part>
-<part name="detail"> 
<detail> 
Process not found.
the BPEL process "MapProductRuleProcess" with revision "1.0" is not loaded.
The process was not initialized properly, or the process was disabled.
Set the logging level to debug mode, check the log for the underlying 
exception trace related to this process loading problem.
</detail>
</part>
</remoteFault>
</bpelFault>
</fault>
-<faultType> 
<message> 
0
</message>
</faultType>
</messages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, a bounce of the server resolved this error!

Comment: What do you mean by bounce back?

Comment: I mean a restart of the server